# How to validate a date (year) using knockout JS?

Tags: javascript, date, knockout.js

I would like to validate the year using knockoutJS library .
The issue that I am facing is that there is no validation for the year when the user types a wrong year. Below are the cases of a wrong year.

```
(01/01/12  becomes 01/01/0012)
(01/01/01  becomes 01/01/0001)
(01/01/111 becomes 01/01/0111)
(01/01/00  becomes 01/01/0000)
```

How can I validate the year if it is wrong?
I am using knockout JS.

Thank you in advance guys!!

Comment: Sounds like you need validation : https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation

Comment: Thanks @4imble !! I'll check the link.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like parsing date values is the issue. Using [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com) with [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) has worked for me in the past:

- [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) - date/time parsing library
- [knockout.moment](https://github.com/civicsource/knockout.moment) -
  knockout extenders for moment.js

Answer (score 0):

similar  to the answer above referencing knockout and moment js. here is one I did (I didn't use an extender but rather just a computed and the css binding to add has error to the bootstrap form group.

```js
function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.myDate = ko.observable('');
  this.myDateisValid = ko.computed(function() {
    return moment(this.myDate(), "MM/DD/YYYY", true).isValid();
  }, this);
}

var myViewModel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group" data-bind="css: {'has-error': !myDateisValid() }">
  <label for="date">Date:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" data-bind="textInput: myDate">
</div>

Date is Valid: <label data-bind="text: myDateisValid"></label>
```